Query About rsvd metric displayed in the memory panel of the esxtop
I have set up a home lap environment 3 esxi hosts running 4 vms including vcsa. I have not configured any reservation yet and I have not enabled the HA and DRS as well. However I see the rsvd memory metrics in the memory panel of the esxtop command reads as 5984 MB every time. As per my understanding, this metric is to display the amount of machine memory currently reserved  by the resource pools. Can Someone explain me why the value is high when I have not configured any reservation in the environment? Thanks a lot in advance.
